# When a message being sent to DLQ

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to understand when and by what trigger exactly message can be thrown to DLQ.

For example, there is a schema below, where **SNS** produces messages into **SQS** and some **Spring Service** consumes this SQS.

[image: Simple SQS pattern]

If we attach **DLQ** to the **Main queue**, we can configure `Maximum receives` parameter (depicted below). I don't get it from documentation, if, for example, `Maximum receives` equals to 1, and **Spring Service** makes an attempt to consume a message from the SQS and fails for some reason after the very first attempt, that message will go into DLQ, right?

And so, if we want to give the **Spring Service** a few more attempts for consumption a message we need to increase `Maximum receives` parameter?

[image: DLQ settings]

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear how it works?

Comment: Hey @Marcin, seems I got the point, thank you very much 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And so, if we want to give the Spring Service a few more attempts for consumption a message we need to increase Maximum receives parameter?

Yes. That's right. To minimize that, you have to ensure that your [SQS visibility timeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html) is adequate for the processing. If the processing time is variable, you can also modify the [visibility time per message](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html#changing-message-visibility-timeout), e.g. by extending it ever 30 s in your spring application.